# Packing run time dependecies into aar library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I build an Android `Application` which contains a module as library. Most of the logic is inside the `LibraryModule`. The library module has several other dependencies which are included as gradle dependencies

`Application 
 * LibraryModule
   *implementation ('dependency1')
   *implementation ('dependency2')`

The library module is include in the application's `build.gradle` like

`implementation project(":LibraryModule")`

The application works fine then.

But when I first build the Library module as an aar file using

`gradle :LibraryModule:assemble`

and then using the applications `build.gradle` to include the aar

`implementation(':LibraryModule@aar')` The application compiles. But several of the classes of the dependencies (`dependency1`, `dependency2`) which are required at run time are missing from the aar.

Is there some way to include all the contents of the `dependency1` and `dependency2` in the aar file so that run time dependecies is also packed together in the aar file.

I have done some googling and found out that [fat aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar) is an option. Is there some way to  include all the  class file from the dependeices also into the aar file which are also needed at run time ?

Answer (score 0):

Building a **fat-aar** is not officially supported by Android. There are some similar discussions at [Android gradle multiproject dependency resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129245/android-gradle-multiproject-dependency-resolution/51131236#51131236)